# Customizing Search Results

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a column FullName in my vb2010 datagrid (database made by SQL Server 2008)
I am using this code at my search bar(Tbx1) and Filter Combobox(Cbx1)

```
If Cbx1.Text = "FullName" Then
        Me.StudentsBindingSource.Filter = "FullName = '" & Tbx1.Text & "'"
```

The problem is if the Full Name is HENRY RAMBO KANAMBO, and i search for RAMBO, I'll get no result unless i Search the Full Name.
Is there a way to handle this inconvenience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use :

```
Me.StudentsBindingSource.Filter = "FullName Like '%" & Tbx1.Text & "%'"
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly? How about displaying a no result found Msgbox?

Comment: You can view answer in other question!

Answer (score -1):

Try using the % wildcard may be.http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp